# Create function that subsets by flexible values in R

Tags: r, function, subset

I would like to create a function that takes various values for a given argument and subsets by any number of them. For example, in the following function, I'l like the function to take any permutation of "yr" including multiple of them:

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(yr = sample(seq(2000,2004,1), 100, replace =TRUE), x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

sum.fun <- function(frame, year){
        print(sum(frame[frame$yr == year,]$x))
}

sum.fun(frame, "2002")
sum.fun(frame, "2004")

sum.fun(frame, c("2002", "2004"))
```

The final line, however, doesn't actually give the sum of both 2002 and 2004. Any thoughts on how to alter the function so that it can take any range of "yr"? Thanks.

Comment: Why put quotes around `2002`, or `c(2002, 2004)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use %in% instead of ==

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(yr = sample(seq(2000,2004,1), 100, replace =TRUE), x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

sum.fun <- function(frame, year){
        print(sum(frame[frame$yr %in% year,]$x))
}

sum.fun(frame, "2002")
sum.fun(frame, "2004")

sum.fun(frame, c("2002", "2004"))
```